# Grouping by with aggregating using different columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, calculated-columns, pandas-groupby

Have a dataframe in pandas with IDs and the days of delivery (for example, 7 days a week):
[image]

I'd like to use groupby() pandas function and create the following-create 7 distinct columns for each day (for example, delivery_day_1, delivery_day_2, etc.) and count the occurences grouping by the ID within a dataframe. How can one do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) or [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) for reshape first.

Then if necessary add missing `weekday`s by [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html) and last [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'subscription_id':[1,2,3,1], 'delivery_weekday':[1,1,2,1]})

print (df)
   delivery_weekday  subscription_id
0                 1                1
1                 1                2
2                 2                3
3                 1                1
```

---

```
df = df.groupby(['subscription_id','delivery_weekday']) \
       .size() \
       .unstack(fill_value=0) \
       .reindex_axis(range(1,8), fill_value=0, axis=1) \
       .add_prefix('delivery_day_')

print (df)
delivery_weekday  delivery_day_1  delivery_day_2  delivery_day_3  \
subscription_id                                                    
1                              2               0               0   
2                              1               0               0   
3                              0               1               0   

delivery_weekday  delivery_day_4  delivery_day_5  delivery_day_6  \
subscription_id                                                    
1                              0               0               0   
2                              0               0               0   
3                              0               0               0   

delivery_weekday  delivery_day_7  
subscription_id                   
1                              0  
2                              0  
3                              0
```

---

```
df = pd.crosstab(df['subscription_id'],df['delivery_weekday']) \
       .reindex_axis(range(1,8), fill_value=0, axis=1) \
       .add_prefix('delivery_day_')
print (df)

delivery_weekday  delivery_day_1  delivery_day_2  delivery_day_3  \
subscription_id                                                    
1                              2               0               0   
2                              1               0               0   
3                              0               1               0   

delivery_weekday  delivery_day_4  delivery_day_5  delivery_day_6  \
subscription_id                                                    
1                              0               0               0   
2                              0               0               0   
3                              0               0               0   

delivery_weekday  delivery_day_7  
subscription_id                   
1                              0  
2                              0  
3                              0
```